# Laravel passport is working on localhost but not on heroku

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, laravel-passport

I am working on an authentication (login & registration) application using java (android).

Now in order to communicate with a database I was requested to implement it using Laravel web app. I configured everything (Laravel passport) and tested it using postman.

I deployed the website on Heroku and configured pgsql with it. then I duplicated the request in postman and changed the URL.

**the problem is that it is adding the new user in the database but it is returning 500 internal server error with no access token**

```
postman response when adding the user:
```

[image]

```
the new user in the db:
```

[image]

```
the code responsible for adding users (same code is still working on localhost)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking to the heroku logs and actually trying to see what is the error?

Comment: where can I reach these logs? lead me please

Comment: Navigate to your heroku dashboard, then to the project, then find "More" button and there should be "view logs" option.

Comment: read this page and look for "trusted proxies" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an error after creating the user. You receive a server-side 500 response because it is not sending you the correct headers to respond in json.

Some APIs require you to send particular headers along with requests, typically to provide additional metadata about the operation you are performing. You can set these up in the Headers tab. Enter any key-value pairs you need and Postman will send them along with your request. As you type, Postman will prompt you with common options you can use to autocomplete your setup, such as `Accept`

Make sure you are sending `Accept: application/json` and in your `.env` file this `APP_DEBUG=true` to see the error.